# Postgresql Select and display one column based on another column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, group-by

#### WALLET TABLE

ID   IS_SPEND   HOWMUCH

1. true.      500
2. false.     1000
3. true.      5

I want to calculate how much money I have after several transactions.

spend as spend money and not spend as earn money

I tried

```sql
select is_spend, sum(howmuch) from table group by is_spend
```

But it cannot reach my goal.

I don't know how can I get the result I want,

just output `495` is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select sum(case when is_spend then -howmuch else howmuch end)
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Could subtract two conditional sums:

```
SELECT COALESCE (sum(howmuch) FILTER (WHERE NOT IS_SPEND), 0)
     - COALESCE (sum(howmuch) FILTER (WHERE IS_SPEND), 0)  AS total
FROM   tbl;
```

But you'll need to add `COALESCE` if you cannot be certain that both types exist.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(HOWMUCH) FROM TABLE WHERE IS_SPEND = '0') - (SELECT SUM(HOWMUCH) FROM TABLE WHERE IS_SPEND = '1') AS GOAL;
```